# Perform a Python Split on a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Test_Step_ID': ['9.1.1', '9.1.2', '9.1.3', '9.1.4'],
        'Protocol_Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        'Req_ID': ['SRS_0081d', 'SRS_0079', 'SRS_0082SRS_0082a', 'SRS_0015SRS_0015cSRS_0015d']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to duplicate the rows based on the column "Req_ID" based on the "SRS" value keeping all other columns values same; hence I want 2 rows for the SRS_0082, SRS_0082a and then three rows for SRS_0015, SRS_0015c, SRS_0015d

Can someone help me here? appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.
[EDITED]:

I want the result to look like this:
[image]

Comment: It will be helpful if you show what the result should look like in an excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) on the zero width location between `SRS` and a preceding character using the `'(?<=.)(?=SRS)` regex, and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
out = (df
  .assign(Req_ID=df['Req_ID'].str.split(r'(?<=.)(?=SRS)'))
  .explode('Req_ID')
 )
```

Output:

```
  Test_Step_ID Protocol_Name     Req_ID
0        9.1.1             A  SRS_0081d
1        9.1.2             B   SRS_0079
2        9.1.3             C   SRS_0082
2        9.1.3             C  SRS_0082a
3        9.1.4             D   SRS_0015
3        9.1.4             D  SRS_0015c
3        9.1.4             D  SRS_0015d
```

Regex:

```
(?<=.)  # match any character before the split
(?=SRS) # match "SRS" after the split
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nQwC0E/1)

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your code, you can try -

```
df['Req_ID'] = df['Req_ID'].str.split('SRS_')

df = df.explode('Req_ID')

df['Req_ID'] = df['Req_ID'].str.strip()
df = df[df['Req_ID'].ne('')]

df['Req_ID'] = 'SRS_' + df['Req_ID']

print(df)
```